# Process parent ID of child process is different from PID of parent

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pid

I'm trying to work with multiple processes in Linux using `fork()` function in C, this is my code:

```
p1 = fork();

if(p1 != 0){
    p2 = fork();
}

printf("My PID is %d\n",getpid());
printf("My parent PID is %d\n",getppid());
```

Now let's assume the parent process ID is 100, and the two child processes (p1, p2) IDs are 101 & 102, and the init process PID will be 0 my expected output is:

```
My PID is 100
My parent PID is 0

My PID is 101
My parent PID is 100

My PID is 102
My parent PID is 100
```

Instead i see something different, the two child processes have the same PPID but the first process has a different PID from that. Here is a sample output i got:

```
My PID is 3383
My parent PID is 3381

My PID is 3387
My parent PID is 1508

My PID is 3386
My parent PID is 1508
```

My question is, shouldn't the parent PID of the two child processes be **3383**?
Hope someone can explain how it all works here and what am i doing (or thinking) wrong.

Comment: What happens when you add a sleep after both `printf` are done?

Comment: @MohitJain it actually fixed it, how does it happen? I mean a sleep After the `printf` shouldn't really change anything, since the processes will be created and `fork` the same...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Confirmed from the comments]

Your output is timing dependant. If the parent process finishes after the children process, your output will be as expected.

If parent process finishes before the children process, output may be surprising (Before parent does not exist any more, parent id would be different).  Once parent process dies (ends), init or some other **implementation-defined** process(1508 in your case), becomes the new parent of the child(ren). Such children are called orphan process(es).

According to the [exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html) man page from The Single UNIX Specification, Version 2:

> The parent process ID of all of the existing child processes and zombie processes of the calling process shall be set to the process ID of an implementation-defined system process. That is, these processes shall be inherited by a special system process.

To avoid this, ensure that parent process is alive at the time of fetching parent pid. One way to do this is to add a wait in parent (or all) process before exiting.

Comment: Makes sense, but still `1508` is a strange PID for `init`.

Comment: @alk It is not necessarity init. pid of init is 1. Actually the ppid of orphan is set to implementation-defined process id.

Comment: "*implementation-defined*" in terms of what, the OS? This is Linux here. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: I confirmed that the output is due to the parent process exiting too soon.  As a quick-and-dirty test, I added a `sleep(1);` call before exiting, and the PIDs were then as originally expected.

Comment: I am aware that with newer kernels one could define a process specific reaper, but did the OP do this?

Comment: @alk Yes kernel specs.

Comment: BTW you perhaps want to update the link in your answer to a recent version of the specifications: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html

Answer (score 1):

There is Nothing Wrong with Your Code

Its Just that your parent process exits before the child processes finish
hence they become orphan and are adopted by init or any implementation-defined process(1508 in your case).

try puttin wait(); for parent to finish the execution of all the child processes.